# Passing data from native UI elements to a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am currently using Highcharts to render a chart to display certain data. And to display the data, user is required to make certain selection, such as the date and type of data they want to view.

Currently, the selections are done within webview using html to lay out the textboxes and submit button, and processed using javascript. So aesthetically, it's quite unpleasing.

**So my question is**, is it possible, and if possible, how can I come about allowing user to input their selection using native UI elements such as EditText and Button, and then `onClick` of the button in the activity class, send the data to the webview to be rendered? E.g. any libraries that can allow such procedure.

Not sure if this helps but currently, I am sending data retrieved from SQLite to the webview using the javascript interface.

Comment: ... sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: I know right. :| But yea, it would be good if it can be achieved. Otherwise, styling of the HTML elements would be inevitable i guess...

Comment: If you just want some **very basic** HTML formatting (i.e.: color, bold, italic, ...), you can use TextViews. Simply use `Html.fromHtml()` and you're good to go. Mind that TextViews are much more performant than WebViews